# скрыть экранную клавиатуру Unity IOS

Tags: unity3d, ios, клавиатура

Всем привет. У меня почему-то при запуске приложения на устройстве IOS всплывает клавиатура, проверял на аndroid - там не всплывает. При помощи интернета нашел код, который должен отключать клавиатуру эту, но он не работает.
Вот этот код, который висит на "MainCamera":

```
    public class HideKeyboard : InputField
{
    protected override void Start()
    {
        keyboardType = (TouchScreenKeyboardType)(-1);
        base.Start();
    }

    protected override void LateUpdate()
    {

        base.LateUpdate();

        if (this.m_Keyboard == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        this.m_Keyboard.active = false;
        this.m_Keyboard = null;
    }
}
```

Также в другом скрипте указал еще один способ:

```
TouchScreenKeyboard keyboard = TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.Default, false, false, false);
    keyboard.active = false;
```

Может кто-то знает иные способы?

Answer (score 0):

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Keyboard : MonoBehaviour
{
   TouchScreenKeyboard keyboard;
   
   private void Start()
   {
      keyboard.active = false;
   }
}
```

Как я полагаю, у вас ничего не срабатывает из-за того что у вас класс InputField, а не MonoBehaviour.

Comment: у меня в другом скрипте прописано подобное:
TouchScreenKeyboard keyboard = TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.Default, false, false, false);
        keyboard.active = false;

но клавиатура все равно всплывает на устройстве, хотя это вызывается при запуске приложения и класс MonoBehavior :(